# Printing a list using python

Tags: python

I have a list compiled from excel cells, using python - say `listlist`. Each element in the cell/list is in unicode. When I print the list as

```
print listlist
```

I see 'u' prepended to each member of the list. But when I print the list like

```
for member in listlist:
  print member
```

I do not see the 'u' prepended to the member.

Can someone please explain to me why there is this difference? Is it defined in the xlrd module?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because `print list` is equivalent to

```
print "[", ", ".join(repr(i) for i in list), "]"
```

`repr(s)` is `u"blabla"` for a unicode string while `print s` prints only `blabla`.

Answer (score 4):

When printing the list, it shows each object within the list using the object's `__repr__`

When printing the object alone, it uses the object's `__str__`

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to turn a Python value into a string `str` and `repr` (and their equivalent class methods `__str__` and `__repr__`). The difference comes from these two functions. From the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html):

> The str() function is meant to return representations of values which are fairly human-readable, while repr() is meant to generate representations which can be read by the interpreter (or will force a SyntaxError if there is not equivalent syntax).

The `print` statement calls `str` on the object you pass in, but the list's `__str__` method calls `repr` on it's values. The values of your list are unicode strings. In human readable form the fact it's unicode is irrelevent, so you don't get a `u`, or even quote marks. In computer readable form it is important, so the `u` is included.

Answer (score 1):

when you are printing a list, python prints a representation of the list.

the default representation of a list is to print an opening square brackets (`[`), then the representation of each element separated by a comma (`,`), the a closing square bracket (`]`). (to be precise the representation of an object is what is returned when calling its `__repr__()` member). note that the default representation of a unicode string is `u'...'`.

now, when you are printing a string, you are not printing the *representation* of the string, you are printing the string (the value returned by calling the `__str__()` member). and the string does not include formatting charaters like unicode flags, quotes, etc...